# Associate vertex coordinates and labels

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

This sounds easy (in which case I will delete my question) and maybe I am getting a bit tired, but I can't find an easy way to create a list from an automatically-generated graph where vertices labels and coordinates are associated, e.g. `{index_vertex, {x,y}}`.

From this image...

[image]

...here is my code so far:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZNrE.png"];
mask = FillingTransform[Thinning[Binarize[ColorReplace[image, White -> Black, .055], 0]], CornerNeighbors -> True];
skel = Thinning[mask];
morphograph = MorphologicalGraph[skel, VertexSize -> 2, VertexLabels -> "Index"];
newtreegraph = TreeGraph[DeleteCases[EdgeList[morphograph], x_ [UndirectedEdge] x_], VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[morphograph], VertexSize -> 5, VertexLabels -> "Index"]
```

that generates this nice `TreeGraph`

[image]

From that, I can obtain the `EdgeList` and vertices coordinates via `GraphEmbedding` but cannot easily connect the two... There must be an easy way I can't find ... Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
AssociationThread[
 VertexList[newtreegraph],
 PropertyValue[newtreegraph, VertexCoordinates]
 ]
```

> <|1 -> {677.5, 957.5}, 8 -> {677.5, 953.5}, <<459>>, 455 -> {300.5, 84.5}|>

Comment: Instead of `PropertyValue[newtreegraph, VertexCoordinates]` you can also use `GraphEmbedding[newtreegraph]`.

Comment: Yes thanks! That was indeed pretty easy...

Comment: You're welcome! Might seem easy (afterwards), but this was also a question worthwhile to ask (+1).